# Repaint image after user input

Tags: java, repaint, fractals

So, for my project, I have decided to create a fractal simulator and so far my code does output a working fractal if the Complex Number Values that the user enters are entered manually i.e. Object created  -> ComplexNumber cn = new ComplexNumber(0.004,-0768). However, to take my code one step further, I wish to have user input in order to make my simulation more user-friendly so I created a JButton for x-Coordinate and JTextField to get the user input. The problem is, no matter what I enter for the input, my fractal does not change and remains the same. I have been trying to fix this for a long time with no success, so any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks :)

**Fractal Code:**

```
// The width and height of the JFrame window.
private static final int WIDTH = 800;// Fractal best rendered as a box format hence, HEIGHT = WIDTH.
private static final int HEIGHT = 480;
// Complex Number class instantiation and object c created with hard coded values for the JuliaSet to be fed.
ComplexNumber c = new ComplexNumber(xCoordinate, 0.281);  //Error here?
protected double xCoordinate;
// Boolean pixel Array to represent two colours plotting a fractal based off true or false if it is in the Julia Set.
private boolean[][] pixels = null;
// The limits of the Complex Plane for which the fractal is bounded between.
private double minX = -1.5;
private double maxX = 1.5;
private double minY = -1.5;
private double maxY = 1.5;

// The image to draw my fractal upon.
private BufferedImage image = null;
private JButton xValueInputButton;
private JTextField xValueInput;
private JPanel panel;

// The recursiveLimit of the ComplexNumber to be allowed in the Set. Depth also relates to detail of the fractal.
private double depth = 1;
// The number of times that the algorithm recursilevly calls itself.
private int iterations = 50;   // Optimum = 50 use 1 for testing

public Fractals(){
    // Create a BufferedImage to paint on.
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    // Fill the boolean[][].
    getPixels();
    // Go through the array and set the pixel color on the BufferedImage
    // according to the pixels in the array.
    for(int i=0;i<WIDTH;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<HEIGHT;j++){
            // If the point is in the Set, color it White, else, color it Black.
            if(pixels[i][j]) image.setRGB(i, j, Color.MAGENTA.getRGB());
            if(!pixels[i][j]) image.setRGB(i, j, Color.BLACK.getRGB());
        }
    }

    // Create a Frame to display the Fractal.
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Fractalis");
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    xValueInput = new JTextField(10);
    xValueInputButton = new JButton("Apply");
    xValueInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 35));
    JPanel inputsPanel = new JPanel();
    panel = new JPanel(){
        // Override the paint method (for simplicity)
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g){
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    };
    // Set other Frame settings.
    f.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.add(inputsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    inputsPanel.add(xValueInput);
    inputsPanel.add(xValueInputButton);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().setBackground(null);
    f.setSize(960,640);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

protected void xValueInputButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    xCoordinate = ((Double.parseDouble(xValueInput.getText())));
}
```

Comment: You have to rebuild `image` with the new values, and call `repaint()` on the panel .

Comment: @Berger -  how do I do that?

Comment: I suppose you will have to replace your `ComplexNumber` with a new one created with the new values, call `getPixels();`, and recompute your `for` loops. It will be easier if you make a new method that performs those three steps.

Comment: @Berger - Are you suggesting something like so?                                                      
    public void repaint(){
        ComplexNumber updatedC = new ComplexNumber(xCoordinate, 0.01);
        getPixels();
        for(int i=0;i<WIDTH;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<HEIGHT;j++){
                // If the point is in the Set, color it White, else, color it Black.
                if(pixels[i][j]) image.setRGB(i, j, Color.MAGENTA.getRGB());
                if(!pixels[i][j]) image.setRGB(i, j, Color.BLACK.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }